# Scraping player data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape football stats with BeautifulSoup and I am trying to get the player's name from the 'a' tag and having no luck.

Here is my current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/rushing.htm#rushing_and_receiving::rush_yds'

req = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'lxml')
players = []
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    player = row.find_all('td', {'data-stat':'player'})
    print(player)
```

Here are the first few examples of what is being returned:

```
[<td class="left" csk="Henry,Derrick" data-append-csv="HenrDe00" data-stat="player"><a href="/players/H/HenrDe00.htm">Derrick Henry </a>*</td>]
[<td class="left" csk="Cook,Dalvin" data-append-csv="CookDa01" data-stat="player"><a href="/players/C/CookDa01.htm">Dalvin Cook</a>*</td>]
[<td class="left" csk="Jacobs,Josh" data-append-csv="JacoJo01" data-stat="player"><a href="/players/J/JacoJo01.htm">Josh Jacobs</a>*</td>]
```

How do I get just the text so I get the name of the player? Is there a simpler way to do this than what I have started?

This is what I would like:

```
Derrick Henry
Dalvin Cook
Josh Jacobs
```

I have tried the following with my loop but getting errors:

```
for row in rows:
        player = row.find_all('td', {'data-stat':'player'}).text
        print(player)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop to get the names, `find_all` returns a `ResultSet` (which is a `list` of elements found using the selectors). You want to use `find` instead

```
for row in rows:
    player = row.find('td', {'data-stat':'player'})
    if player:
        player = player.text
        print(player)
```